# AWS EC2 billed hours per instance in a given time period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My CIO is asking me for a monthly "per instance" breakdown of EC2 charges, as some of our EC2 instances are run on behalf specific customers. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I can use java, python, or the aws command line tools if necessary, but a report tools or service is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is fairly new tool open-sourced by Netflix called [Ice](https://github.com/Netflix/ice) which allows you to visualize the billing details as retrieved via the AWS reports generated into your S3 buckets.

You might also want to check the answers over at serverfault to a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/350971/how-can-i-monitor-daily-spending-on-aws/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to tag resources associated with a particular customer (for example EC2 instances, RDS) and enable the `Detailed Billing Report`.

Log into the `My Account` area of the console and go to the `Billing Preferences` area. Enable `Monthly Report`, `Programmatic Access` and `Detailed Billing Report`.

AWS will start to aggregate your billing to a nominated S3 bucket as CSV files and break it down by tags. There will be a charge for the storage on S3.

Aggregation by tags only starts from when you turn it on so you won't get the full month till the next report.

More details [here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/aws-cost-allocation.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/getbill.html#allocation) for how to set up and analyse the data.

Answer (score 2):

Tag the instance ,it will reflect in your bills based on your tags .

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to enable detailed billing export to a S3 bucket (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html))

Then I wrote a simplistic server in Python that retrieves your detailed bill and breaks it down per service-type and usage type (see it on this GitHib [repo](https://github.com/oddskool/aws_billing)).

Thus you can check anytime what your costs are and which services cost you the most etc.

If you tag your EC2 instances, S3 buckets etc, they will also show up on a dedicated line.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cloudability, and our tool is built to do exactly that. It collects AWS billing and usage data as well as your tags from all of your accounts and puts it into a custom reporting interface. It's completely point-and-click so you don't have to mess around with writing scripts or building spreadsheets.

A lot of companies are using it to do exactly what you're talking about ... split up costs/usage by instance, department, project, client, etc..

You can check it out at https://cloudability.com